# find() with equal and like in sails

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I'd like to execute a query like this,

```
select * from user where user.status = 'ban' and
user.status = 'new' and
user.username like 'fo%' // in code I will get this from req.param('user')
```

I know how to do like this,

```
var username = req.param('user');
var status = req.param('status');
User.find().where({ status : [status, 'new'], username : username }).exec(function(err, users){
        console.log(users);
});
```

But I don't know how to use "like" for the username.

How should I do.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var username = req.param('user');
var status = req.param('status');
User.find({
    status: [status, 'new'],
    username: {
        'startsWith': username
    }
}).exec(function(err, users) {
    console.log(users);
});
```

Give that a try

and for reference, here is a link to documentation about the waterline query format
https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/query-language.md

Answer (score 0):

Kinda old, but if anyone else stumbles across this one. You could also use the 'contains' keyword like so:

```
const result = await User.find({
  name : {
    'contains' : inputs.username
  }
});
```

Also here's the updated/moved link to waterline query language description 2022:
https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/query-language

Check the modifiers:

```
'<' 
'<=' 
'>' 
'>=' 
'!=' 
nin 
in 
contains 
startsWith 
endsWith
```